# Extract RSA public key from a x509 char array with openssl

Tags: c, openssl

Here is a certificate in x509 format that stores the public key and the modulo:

```
const unsigned char *certificateDataBytes = {/*data*/};
```

Using OpenSSL and C, how can I convert it into an RSA object?  I've tried several methods but I can't get it to work in `RSA_public_encrypt`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you mean public key into RSA * structure.

Since, you have certificate in bytes, if it is in DER encoded bytes, then you need to first convert it into X509 * structure.

```
 X509 * cert;
 EVP_PKEY * pubkey;
 //length is the length of the certificateDataBytes in terms of bytes.
 cert = d2i_x509 (NULL, certificateDataBytes, length);
 pubkey = X509_get_pubkey (cert);
```

Please note that if certificate has RSA public key, then you can get RSA public key as follows:

```
 RSA * rsa
 rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pubkey);

 //Now rsa contains RSA public key. Use it.

 //After use, free the pubkey
 EVP_PKEY_free (pubkey);
```

I hope this must solve your purpose.
If certificate encoding is different, use different function. Once, you get X509 *, rest step is same.

Comment: It turns out that cert becomes null.  I have it in ASN.1 format.  That's the same as DER encoded correct?  What's happening

Comment: @blake305: Generally, ASN.1 is DER encoded. However, other encodings are also possible. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example_encoded_in_DER for DER encoding example. cert is becoming NULL means it may not be valid. Use ERR_print_errors_fp (FILE *fp) to get the last error into a file. It may give meaningful description.

Comment: Don't forget to free the ```RSA*``` by calling ```RSA_free``` !